# Download azure blob storage file in angular

Tags: angularjs, azure-blob-storage, wavesurfer.js

Is there any way to download a wav file from an Azure Blob storage in Angular?
I would like to play it with wavesurfer.js

Comment: For searchers wanting an API based approach (to enable permissions checking etc), I've made a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/HockeyJustin/087c6f08bb4f328e196138123d294f9e)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can access the wav file directly with the Blob URL.

For example, you can use Azure Storage Explorer which can be download from [here](http://storageexplorer.com/), to generate SAS (Shared Access Signature) and get the Blob URI.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Once you got the URI of the Bolb, you can play it with wavesurfer.js like this:

```
wavesurfer.load('https://<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<ContainerName>/<WavFileName><QueryString>');
```

---

### Edit:

The simplest way to visit your blob without any query string is to set the container permissions to allow public access. Then it will be available on the URL (here I'm assuming your blob file is called *audio.wav*):

```
https://<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/<ContainerName>/audio.wav
```

> To set container permissions from the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. Navigate to the dashboard for your storage account.
> 2. Select the container name from the list. Click the name that exposes the blobs in the chosen container.
> 3. Select **Access policy** from the toolbar.
> 4. In the **Access type** field, select your desired level of permissions as shown in the screenshot below.
>
> [image]

For more details, see [Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-manage-access-to-resources).

Comment: But do I need a different query string for each file I want to download? I found this example on how to define a blob url:  **https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/sascontainer/sasblob.txt?sv=2014-02-14&st=2014-12-23T22%3A18%3A26Z&se=2014-12-23T22%3A23%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rw&sig=Z%2FRHIX5Xcg0Mq2rqI3OlWTjEg2tYkboXr1P9ZUXDtkk%3D**.         I only have an Azure access key for my blob container

Comment: I read different ways to do it and everywhere is said that you can use a SAS, as you explained or you can just do it with the storage account name and key.The question is:how do I have to use those parameters in order to get a wav file from the blob?